# The return value of getRefreshRate() in android?

Tags: android

Does this value means refresh rate of current view, or the physical refresh rate of the screen?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate()

```
public float getRefreshRate ()
Gets the refresh rate of this display in frames per second.
```

Comment: What I want to know is the physical refresh rate of the screen.

Comment: The return value is `float`, a decimal number.

Comment: cuurent view........

Comment: thanks..........Then is there a "physical refresh rate"...?